# Add new printer to Control Center 4

Tags: printer

I have problem about ControlCenter 4. I need add my another printer to this application but despite a lot of attempts still there is not possible. Its strange because I can use this printer so scanning and printing is possible and even its set to my default printer what you can see on one of my attached photos but I cant add this printer to ControlCenter4. I made resets of printer etc but still not working. In Internet I found solution for this, I mean that there is necessary to install Full Driver & Software Package. But unfortunetly while i am making it there is error which you can see in my attached screens. Could you help me how i can resolve this problem?

Attached screens:

https://i.ibb.co/Hg6LfVf/1.png 
https://i.ibb.co/SKW0xLk/2.png 
https://i.ibb.co/cYXc9jd/3.png 
https://i.ibb.co/sH0S0Q1/4.png

Comment: Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: Please add your operating system as  a tag on the question.